# Application.Caller / Storing worksheet name as string

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to store the CurrentWorksheet name in order to reference it in a different Sub routine.

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
Private Sub InsertNewBill_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets(CurrentWorksheet).Range("A30:L30")
rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Current Worksheet Function:

```
Function CurrentWorksheet()
CurrentSheet = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name
End Function
```

I need to try to reference the "CurrentSheet" variable in the "InsertNewBill" Sub routine.

The function of this is to insert a new line of cells between "A30:L30" on the currently selected worksheet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-activesheet-property-excel)?

Comment: Your function btw, is called `CurrentWORKSheet`, but you close it with `CurrentSheet` so it will never return a value.

Comment: I think Vincent is right - but beside this: Don't deal with worksheet *names*, deal with worksheet *objects*

Comment: @VincentG I believe thats close to what i need, however my VBA is a little rusty. Essentially what that MsgBox is doing is pretty much what i then need to transfer to the InsertNewBill

Comment: And always use `Option Explicit` to avoid mistakes with the names as CLR wrote

Comment: @CLR Thank you for pointing that out. My Apologies

Comment: @FunThomas Can i ask what the difference is? It does now give me an issue with "Object required" but im unsure how to resolve it.

Comment: A Worksheet is an *object*. You are already accessing such an object, for example with `Worksheets(CurrentWorksheet)`. `activesheet` is also such an object, and you can declare your own worksheet variables. A string is just a string - in your case the *name* of a sheet, but technically only a bunch of characters. If you want to deal with *objects* in VBA, you have to assign it using the command `set`. But I think you should get rid of the `caller` function in the first place (personally, I have never used it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't plan to write this as answer, but to explain to `Batteredburrito` how to deal with objects rather than names:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub InsertNewBill_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = currentWorksheet.Range("A31:AC31")
    rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Current Worksheet Function

```
Function currentWorksheet() As Worksheet
    set currentWorksheet = ActiveSheet
End Function
```

This is doing exactly the same as your version (so you can stick with that), it's just to show how to deal with objects. But there are situations where it is much better to deal with objects that with name - especially if you are dealing with multiple Workbooks (that might have the same sheet names).

And, of course, in the end you could get rid of the function completely by simply writing

```
...
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A31:AC31")
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It really is appreciated. You guys are the best

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help and direction.

I have resolved the issue with the following

Insert new cells between a range of cells on button press:

```
Private Sub InsertNewBill_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets(CurrentWorksheet).Range("A31:AC31")
rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Current Worksheet Function:

```
Function CurrentWorksheet()
CurrentWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
End Function
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A31:C31").Insert Shift:=xlDown` would also do the job.  `ActiveSheet` is exactly the same as writing `Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)` if it's all in the same workbook.